# Javascript “Pikaday is not defined”

Tags: javascript, variables, datepicker

hello everyone javascript function that will allow the user pick his/her date of birth from a pop-up calendar and insert that data into a text field  Pretty basic, but for some reason javascript is telling me that my variable is  not defined and I am confused as to why.

This is the error I get:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Pikaday is not defined

The html is as followed:

```
<tr>
                <td>Fecha de Nacimiento</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input name="bday" type="date" id="datepicker"  size="35" required></td>
</tr>
```

the javascript is as follows

```
<script>
      var picker = new Pikaday({ field: document.getElementById("datepicker") });
```

Comment: You're most likely not loading the Pikaday (?) JS file.

Comment: Are you using a library?  If so, have you actually referenced the library in your HTML?

Comment: `Pikaday` isn't a variable, but an object that you're trying to instantiate. It is probably not referenced right in your code.

Comment: @Dean.DePue It is a day celebrated by Pokémon fans, of course! Pika-pikachu! :3

Comment: add pikaday in before your code ``<script src="pikaday.js"></script>``

Answer (score 0):

Sine the file `pickaday.js` unfortunatelly is not part of the Javascript-Language you need to include it in lines above `new Pickaday` like this:

```
<script src="/js/pickaday.js"></script>
```

You must change the path/filename to your needs.